# Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id'

Tags: php, mysql

I made a profile page for users, but I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1 in C:\wamp64\www\social_network\classes\DB.php on line 12
>   ( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1 in C:\wamp64\www\social_network\classes\DB.php on line 12

I am sure that my `\classes\DB.php` is correct, because it is connected to other php files. This is the "profile page" code that I am using:

Thank you for your time.

```
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0009  391176  {main}( )   ...\profile.php:0
2   0.0329  444848  Post::createPost( ) ...\profile.php:62
3   0.0330  445224  DB::query( )    ...\Post.php:25
4   0.0349  461048  execute ( ) ...\DB.php:12

<?php
include('./classes/DB.php');
include('./classes/Login.php');
include('./classes/Post.php');
include('./classes/Image.php');

$username = "";
$verified = False;
$isFollowing = False;
if (isset($_GET['username'])) {
        if (DB::query('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$_GET['username']))) {

                $username = DB::query('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$_GET['username']))[0]['username'];
                $userid = DB::query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$_GET['username']))[0]['id'];
                $verified = DB::query('SELECT verified FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$_GET['username']))[0]['verified'];
                $followerid = Login::isLoggedIn();

                if (isset($_POST['follow'])) {

                        if ($userid != $followerid) {

                                if (!DB::query('SELECT follower_id FROM followers WHERE user_id=:userid AND follower_id=:followerid', array(':userid'=>$userid, ':followerid'=>$followerid))) {
                                        if ($followerid == 6) {
                                                DB::query('UPDATE users SET verified=1 WHERE id=:userid', array(':userid'=>$userid));
                                        }
                                        DB::query('INSERT INTO followers VALUES (null, :userid, :followerid)', array(':userid'=>$userid, ':followerid'=>$followerid));
                                } else {
                                        echo 'Already following!';
                                }
                                $isFollowing = True;
                        }
                }
                if (isset($_POST['unfollow'])) {

                        if ($userid != $followerid) {

                                if (DB::query('SELECT follower_id FROM followers WHERE user_id=:userid AND follower_id=:followerid', array(':userid'=>$userid, ':followerid'=>$followerid))) {
                                        if ($followerid == 6) {
                                                DB::query('UPDATE users SET verified=0 WHERE id=:userid', array(':userid'=>$userid));
                                        }
                                        DB::query('DELETE FROM followers WHERE user_id=:userid AND follower_id=:followerid', array(':userid'=>$userid, ':followerid'=>$followerid));
                                }
                                $isFollowing = False;
                        }
                }
                if (DB::query('SELECT follower_id FROM followers WHERE user_id=:userid AND follower_id=:followerid', array(':userid'=>$userid, ':followerid'=>$followerid))) {
                        //echo 'Already following!';
                        $isFollowing = True;
                }

                if (isset($_POST['deletepost'])) {
                        if (DB::query('SELECT id FROM posts WHERE id=:postid AND user_id=:userid', array(':postid'=>$_GET['postid'], ':userid'=>$followerid))) {
                                DB::query('DELETE FROM posts WHERE id=:postid and user_id=:userid', array(':postid'=>$_GET['postid'], ':userid'=>$followerid));
                                DB::query('DELETE FROM post_likes WHERE post_id=:postid', array(':postid'=>$_GET['postid']));
                                echo 'Post deleted!';
                        }
                }


                if (isset($_POST['post'])) {
                        if ($_FILES['postimg']['size'] == 0) {
                                Post::createPost($_POST['postbody'], Login::isLoggedIn(), $userid);
                        } else {
                                $postid = Post::createImgPost($_POST['postbody'], Login::isLoggedIn(), $userid);
                                Image::uploadImage('postimg', "UPDATE posts SET postimg=:postimg WHERE id=:postid", array(':postid'=>$postid));
                        }
                }

                if (isset($_GET['postid']) && !isset($_POST['deletepost'])) {
                        Post::likePost($_GET['postid'], $followerid);
                }

                $posts = Post::displayPosts($userid, $username, $followerid);


        } else {
                die('User not found!');
        }
}

?>
<h1><?php echo $username; ?>'s Profile<?php if ($verified) { echo ' - Verified'; } ?></h1>
<form action="profile.php?username=<?php echo $username; ?>" method="post">
        <?php
        if ($userid != $followerid) {
                if ($isFollowing) {
                        echo '<input type="submit" name="unfollow" value="Unfollow">';
                } else {
                        echo '<input type="submit" name="follow" value="Follow">';
                }
        }
        ?>
</form>

<form action="profile.php?username=<?php echo $username; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <textarea name="postbody" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
        <br />Upload an image:
        <input type="file" name="postimg">
        <input type="submit" name="post" value="Post">
</form>

<div class="posts">
        <?php echo $posts; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Want us to count the lines? What is "line 12"?

Comment: oh sorry bro in this code line 12 is empty but in /classes/DB.php is                 $statement->execute($params); and in the database id is an integer

Comment: This error usually occurs for an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` query. So which query in particular is causing that error? What is the `id` column for that table defined as? Are you setting an empty value on purpose, or is it missing an `AUTO_INCREMENT` flag?

Comment: The exception should print the complete stacktrace. Where is it?

Comment: the id in the query followers is AUTO_INCREMENT Primary_KEY  with null no and default none

Comment: paul i am not sure what you mean but i edited my post thank you again for your time

Comment: So the problem is with a query executed from `Post::createPost()` -- I assume this does an `INSERT` query on your `posts` table, is the `id` column there an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column as well?

Comment: yes it is AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: Does that `INSERT` query try to set the `id` column value to `NULL` or to an empty string (`''`)?

Comment: Include the code for `Post::createPost( )` function.

Comment: i am giving that query a null value for id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' [...]

You are trying to save the string/varchar value `''` (an empty string) to the column 'id' which is an integer type. As you cannot save a string in an integer column you get this error message.

Since it is an AUTO_INCREMENT column the solution is to not provide a value for this column at all. You can do this by adding the columns in your `INSERT` statement you want to fill.

```
INSERT INTO Table(colA, colB) VALUES (val1, val2);
```

This way all the remaining columns will get the default or AUTO_INCREMENT values.